# why set fileencoding=cp936 no use?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vim, file-encodings

1. I create a file, execute the following command:

```bash
:set fileencoding
```

2. result is :

```bash
fileencoding=cp936
```

3. I edit and then close the file. I reopen the file and execute the following command:

```bash
:set fileencoding
```

4. result is :

```bash
fileencoding=utf-8
```

The contents of .vimrc are:

```bash
...
set fencs=ucs-bom,utf-8,gbk,gb18030,utf-16,big5
set fenc=cp936
set encoding=utf-8
```

Also, I used a remote connection in vscode.
Why does the value of fileencoding change? What is the reason for this ? How to solve this problem ? thanks!

---

**Here are the results of my attempts:**

1. When the content contains only English, content is as follows,  I save and reopen it. And then i execute the command: set fileencoding, the result is `fileencoding=utf-8`。also, I execute `file test1.c`，the result is `test1.c: ASCII text`.

```cpp
//file: test1.c
abc
```

2. When the content contains Chinese:  content is as follows,  I save and reopen it. And then i execute the command: set fileencoding, the result is `fileencoding=cp936`。also, I execute `file test2.c`，the result is `test2.c: ISO-8859 text`.

```cpp
//file:test2.c
你好abc
```

3. `.vimrc` content is :

```bash
...
set fencs=ucs-bom,utf-8,gbk,gb18030,utf-16,big5
set fenc=cp936
set encoding=utf-8
```

My question is why fileencoding is utf-8 and not cp936 when the content is in English only?

Comment: What is your problem? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: It seems that the Settings in vimrc only take effect when Chinese is present in the document

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. Do you expect your files always to be encoded in cp936? Is that what you're trying to do? Have you read `:help 'fencs'`, `:help 'fenc'` and `:help 'encoding'`? You will see that your options are either set to their defaults or irrelevant.

Comment: I added the question. I expect my files always to be encoded in cp936. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: FWIW, Vim sets `:help 'fileencoding'` on its own when it opens a new file to edit so having it in your `vimrc` is not really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not a Vim issue but an encoding issue. Vim does what you ask for and it does not make a difference.

There are two pieces of information that explain the behavior. The first one is that text files contain no meta information about their encoding. It's actually just a bunch of bytes. How they are interpreted is up to the application. Applications will have to *guess*. Judging from the [bulk of related questions on a popular programming Q&A site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding+text-files), this is hard.

The second piece of the puzzle is that the first 128 characters of both UTF-8 and CP936 are identical to the ASCII character set. Take a look at the [code page file for CP936](https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WindowsBestFit/bestfit936.txt) and compare it with ASCII.

This is by design. So for bytes `0x00` to `0x7f`, it's just plain ASCII, no matter what encoding you specify.

Using Vim, let's create a simple text file containing "hello world" and take a look at it:

```
> xxd ascii.txt 
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 640a            hello world.
> file ascii.txt 
ascii.txt: ASCII text
```

After `set fileencoding=cp936` and saving again, you will get identical results.

Note the complete absence of any encoding meta information. The whole file is just "hello world" and a newline.

Everything changes once you introduce non-ASCII characters. The first non-ASCII in CP936 is the Euro sign encoded as `0x80`. So let's say "h€llo world" and re-run the file investigations:

```
> xxd utf-8.txt 
00000000: 68e2 82ac 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 640a       h...llo world.
> file utf-8.txt
utf-8.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
> xxd cp936.txt
00000000: 6880 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 640a            h.llo world.
> file cp936.txt
cp936.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text
```

Note that € is encoded as `e2 82 ac` as [one would expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding_process) in UTF-8 while it's encoded as `80` in CP936.

Also note that `file` cannot correctly guess CP936 encoding.

As we have seen, there's no difference in file contents as long as only ASCII characters are used. So the bottom line is that Vim saves your ASCII files as CP936 but it doesn't make a difference.

To help Vim get the encoding right when *opening* files, you would add cp936 near the start of `'fileencodings'`.